# Index page redirection to /?lang=ro

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

How can I redirect my website from example.com to example.com/?lang=ro ? I want to set default language to "ro" because it changes only on flag click, I think that i have to set lang variable to "ro", but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to check if query string exists in request URL, if not, then you can append it in your URL.

Check below code :

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !lang
RewriteRule (.*) $1?lang=ro [R=302,QSA,L]
```

This will append query string `lang=ro` and redirect if query string not exist in request URL.

Comment: Thank you very much. It helped me!